# While automating the Oracle forms, script is getting passed even if it is not executed properly (using selenium with robot js and nut js)

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, robotframework, ui-automation, oracleforms

[Here the Another.png not present in that particular form still it is not coming to the catch block .
And even if it doesn't find the correct Capture.png it is clicking somewhere in the form and script is getting passed.

2. post click step 65, getting one popup because of that it is not executing rest of the step still that method getting passed
   Can anyone help me in this for proper validation - it should fail if the step doesn't execute properly] (https://i.stack.imgur.com/mK0zQ.png)

Can anyone help me in this for proper validation - it should fail if the step doesn't execute properly

Comment: I am going to guess and say this is not about Oracle Forms.  If I am correct, please remove the "oracleforms" tag you added.  If you are doing this with Oracle Forms, it would be great if you would share how you set it all up.  I'm sure many others would be grateful to find a Selenium solution that works with Forms.